# Retrieving the <img> tag inside of cdata

Tags: javascript, jquery, cdata

I know what's the meaning of CDATA. But what I wanted for help is if someone could give me the right javascript for getting the img tag inside rrs cdata, please check below content.

My xml file;

```
 <content:encoded>
    <![CDATA[<div> <a> **<img />** </a> </div>  ]]>
 </content:encoded>
```

Script that I'm following (yrss.min.js)..

```
// provisional html result
    htmlObject = $(html);
    // if content option is true... *
    if (options.content) {
    // for each entry... *
    $.each(htmlObject, function () {
    // if image option is true... *
    if (options.image) {
    // * check for first image
    var image = $(this).find('img').first(); <<< doesn't find the img
    // if image exists... *
    if (image.length !== 0) {
    // * create image wrapper`enter code here`
    $(this).prepend('<div class="entry-image">');

    // * append first image in image wrapper and wrap all textual elements after it
    $(this).find('.entry-image').append(image).nextAll().wrapAll('<div class="entry-text"></div>');
      }
    }
```

The whole script:

```
(function ($) {

    // use strict mode
    'use strict';

    $.fn.yrss = function (url, options, fn) {

        // plugin defaults
        var defaults = {
            ssl: false,
            limit: 10,
            reverse: false,
            cache: true,
            maxage: 3600,
            showerror: true,
            errormsg: '',
            tags: false,
            date: true,
            dateformat: 'default',
            titletag: 'h4',
            content: true,
            image: true,
            snippet: true,
            snippetlimit: 120,
            linktarget: '_self'
        };

        // extend options
        options = $.extend(defaults, options);

        // return function
        return this.each(function (i, e) {
            // check for ssl protocol
            var s = '';
            if (options.ssl) { s = 's'; }

            // add class to container
            if (!$(e).hasClass('rss-feed')) { $(e).addClass('rss-feed'); }

            // check for valid url
            if (url === null) { return false; }

            // create yql query
            var query = 'http' + s + '://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' + encodeURIComponent('select * from feed where url="' + url + '"');

            // set limit
            if (options.limit !== null) { query += ' limit ' + options.limit; }

            // reverse feed order
            if (options.reverse) { query += ' | reverse()'; }

            // set maximum cache age
            if (options.cache) { query += '&_maxage=' + options.maxage; }

            // specify format
            query += '&format=json';

            // send request
            $.getJSON(query, function (data, status, errorThrown) {
                // if successful... *
                if (status === 'success') {
                    // * run function to create html result
                    process(e, data, options);

                    // * optional callback function
                    if ($.isFunction(fn)) { fn.call(this, $(e)); }

                    // if there's an error... *
                } else if (status === 'error' || status === 'parsererror') {
                    // if showerror option is true... *
                    if (options.showerror) {
                        // variable scoping (error)
                        var msg;

                        // if errormsg option is not empty... *
                        if (options.errormsg !== '') {
                            // * assign custom error message
                            msg = options.errormsg;

                            // if errormsg option is empty... *
                        } else {
                            // * assign default error message
                            msg = errorThrown;
                        }

                        // * display error message
                        $(e).html('<div class="rss-error"><p>' + msg + '</p></div>');

                        // if showerror option is false... *
                    } else {
                        // * abort
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    };

    // create html result
    var process = function (e, data, options) {
        // feed data (entries)
        var entries = data.query.results.item;

        // check if entries are not inside an array (only 1 entry)
        if (!$.isArray(entries)) { entries = [entries]; }

        // abort if no entries exist
        if (!entries) { return false; }

        // html variables
        var html = '';
        var htmlObject;

        // for each entry... *
        $.each(entries, function (i) {
            // * assign entry variable
            var entry = entries[i];

            // * variable scoping (tags)
            var tags;

            // if entry tags exist... *
            if (entry.category !== undefined) {
                // * arrange entry tags
                tags = entry.category.toString().toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '-').replace(/,/g, ' ');
            }

            // * variable scoping (date)
            var pubDate;

            // if date option is true... *
            if (entry.pubDate) {
                // * create date object
                var entryDate = new Date(entry.pubDate);

                // * select date format
                if (options.dateformat === 'default') {
                    pubDate = (entryDate.getMonth() + 1).toString() + '/' + entryDate.getDate().toString() + '/' + entryDate.getFullYear();
                } else if (options.dateformat === 'spellmonth') {
                    var months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
                    pubDate = months[entryDate.getMonth()] + ' ' + entryDate.getDate().toString() + ', ' + entryDate.getFullYear();
                } else if (options.dateformat === 'localedate') {
                    pubDate = entryDate.toLocaleDateString();
                } else if (options.dateformat === 'localedatetime') {
                    pubDate = entryDate.toLocaleDateString() + ' ' + entryDate.toLocaleTimeString();
                }
            }

            // * build entry
            html += '<div class="entry-wrapper"';
            if (options.tags && entry.category !== undefined) { html += 'data-tag="' + tags + '"'; }
            html += '><div class="entry-title"><' + options.titletag + '><a href="' + entry.link + '">' + entry.title + '</a></' + options.titletag + '></div>';
            if (options.date && pubDate) { html += '<div class="entry-date">' + pubDate + '</div>'; }

            // if content option is true... *
            if (options.content) {
                // * check for rss description/encoded value
                var content;
                if (entry.description !== undefined) {
                    content = $.trim(entry.description);
                } else {
                    content = $.trim(entry.encoded);
                }

                // * build content
                html += '<div class="entry-content">' + content + '</div>';
            }

            html += '</div>';
        });

        // provisional html result
        htmlObject = $(html);

        // if content option is true... *
        if (options.content) {
            // for each entry... *
            $.each(htmlObject, function () {
                // if image option is true... *
                if (options.image) {
                    // * check for first image
                    var image = $(this).find('img').first();

                    // if image exists... *
                    if (image.length !== 0) {
                        // * create image wrapper
                        $(this).prepend('<div class="entry-image">');

                        // * append first image in image wrapper and wrap all textual elements after it
                        $(this).find('.entry-image').append(image).nextAll().wrapAll('<div class="entry-text"></div>');
                    }
                }

                // if snippet option is true... *
                if (options.snippet) {
                    // * set character limit
                    var content = $(this).find('.entry-content');
                    var contentLength = $(content).text().length;
                    content.text(function (i, v) {
                        if (contentLength === 0) {
                            return '';
                        } else if (contentLength !== 0 && contentLength <= options.snippetlimit) {
                            return v;
                        } else {
                            return v.substring(0, options.snippetlimit) + ' ...';
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }

        // append final html result
        $(e).append(htmlObject);

        // apply target to links
        $('a', e).attr('target', options.linktarget);
    };

})(jQuery);
```

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--><html lang="en"><!--<![endif]-->

<head>
    <title>YRSS Demo</title>
    
    <!--meta information-->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <!--scripts
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>-->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="yrss.min.js"></script>
    
    <!--styles
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css">-->
    
    <style>
        html,body {
        -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
        -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;
        background-color:#fff;
        color:#fff;
        font-family:"Montserrat", arial, sans-serif;
        font-size:100%;
        font-weight:400;
        height:100%;
        line-height:1.45;
        }
        
        #wrapper {
        margin:0 auto;
        max-width:1200px;
        padding:3rem 0 5rem;
        width:90%;
        }
        
        .rss-feed {
        -webkit-perspective:1;
        column-fill:balance;
        column-gap:2rem;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        }
        
        .entry-wrapper {
        background-color:#006b3a;
        border-radius:1px;
        display:inline-block;
        margin-bottom:2rem;
        position:relative;
        vertical-align:top;
        width:100%;
        }
        
        .entry-image img {
        border-radius:1px 1px 0 0;
        display:block;
        height:auto;
        max-width:100%;
        width:100%;
        }
        
        .entry-title h4 {
        font-size:1.5rem;
        line-height:1.2;
        }
        
        .entry-title h4 a {
        color:#fff;
        text-decoration:none;
        transition:color 200ms ease-in-out;
        }
        
        .entry-title h4 a:hover {
        color:rgba(255,255,255,.7);
        }
        
        .entry-title h4 a::after {
        content:"\02197";
        margin-left:.5rem;
        }
        
        .entry-date {
        background-color:#006b3a;
        font-size:.75rem;
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        right:0px;
        padding:.25rem .5rem;
        border-radius:0 0 0 1px;
        }
        
        .entry-text {
        border-top:3px solid #00371d;
        padding:1rem;
        }
        
        .entry-content {
        margin:.625rem 0 0;
        }
        
        .entry-content:empty {
        display:none;
        }
        
        @media only screen and (min-width:480px) {
            .rss-feed {
            column-count:1;
            }
        }   
       
   

     </style>
    </head>
    
    <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="feed"></div>
    </div>
    
    <script>
        var feed = ' ---address rss feed--- ';
        $('#feed').yrss(feed, {
            ssl: false,
            limit: 2,
            reverse: false,
            cache: true,
            maxage: 3600,
            showerror: true,
            errormsg: '',
            tags: true,
            date: true,
            dateformat: 'spellmonth',
            titletag: 'h4',
            content: true,
            image: true,
            snippet: true,
            snippetlimit: 120,
            linktarget: '_blank'
        }, function () {
            // optional callback function
        });
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show how the `html` and `options` variables are set. And what is `this`?

Comment: Hi thanks for the comment, what i wanted is to find the img tag inside of cdata, if you check the script above the .find() is not working. Is there any other way or script can find the img inside of cdata?

Comment: So, again, please show how `html` is set. (I've now realised what `this` is; I didn't get it at first due to the lack of indenting.)

Comment: hehe okay, i updated my question, i add the whole script. :)